# Error Installing Firebase Crashalytics in Xcode

Tags: xcode, firebase, crashlytics

When installing pods for firebase crashalytics, I end up getting the following error when building my project:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/charlieseligman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosRpg-adnemhaybfqxtfaseatzgcodrqhn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iosRpg.build/Debug-iphoneos/iosRpg.build/Script-9E0308592720706B102EX692.sh: 
"/Users/charlieseligman/Documents/GIT/ios.SwordyQuest/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Anyone seen this before?  Or have any ideas about debugging it?

Answer (score 2):

I was putting the "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" script in the 'Shell' textfield rather than in the section directly below this... hope this answer helps someone else who is as tired as I am and making silly mistakes also.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution! This is totally what I was doing haha
you saved me.

Comment: Yeah, Google never mentioned specifically where to place this - only "in your new Run Script phase". Thanks!